# Google API and AppsScript

Tags: api, google-apps-script

If I am using Google API ([this one](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/)) to access a GoogleSheet document, do the calls I am making via an API have any impact on the AppsScript-specific URL Fetch Service quota mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe they do. 2 separate quotas. 
[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)